# Pass data from one module to another in Terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I have a `network` module, that creates a VPC and a couple of subnets:

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "this" {
  name                = "${var.app_name}-vnet-${var.environment}"
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group
  location            = var.region
   address_space       = [var.network_address_space]
}
    
resource "azurerm_subnet" "main-subnets" {
  for_each = var.subnets
    
  name                 = each.key == "GatewaySubnet" ? "GatewaySubnet" : "${var.app_name}-subnet-${each.key}-${var.environment}" 
  resource_group_name  = var.resource_group
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.this.name
  address_prefixes     = [cidrsubnet(var.network_address_space, 8, each.value)]
}
```

The subnets are provided via a variable:

```
variable "subnets" {
  default = {
    "a" = 1
  }
  description = "List of subnets to be created."
}
```

In the root module I use the network module like so:

```
module "network-azure" {
  source                = "../../modules/AZURE/network"
  app_name              = var.app_name
  environment           = var.environment
  region                = var.azure_region
  resource_group        = var.azure_resource_group_name
  network_address_space = var.azure_network_address_space
  subnets               = { "a" = 1, "GatewaySubnet" = 2 }
}
```

Later I use another module, where I need the ID of the GatewaySubnet. My first idea was to retrieve it as data:

```
data "azurerm_subnet" "gateway-subnet" {
  name                 = "GatewaySubnet"
  virtual_network_name = var.vnet_name
  resource_group_name  = var.resource_group
}
```

However this gives me the error, that the GatewaySubnet does not exist. Is this normal behaviour? I expected terraform to recognize the dependency.

My second idea was to output the GatewaySubnet ID and use it as variable:

```
output "subnets" {
  value = [for subnet in azurerm_subnet.main-subnets : { "id" : subnet.id, name : subnet.name }]
}
```

and use it

```
module "vpn-azure" {
  source                    = "../../modules/AZURE/vpn"
  app_name                  = var.app_name
  environment               = var.environment
  resource_group            = var.azure_resource_group_name
  region                    = var.azure_region
  gateway_subnet_id         = module...subnets...
}
```

But I am not sure, how to get the ID from the output which is a list of objects. I would have to filter the list by name. Can this be done in terraform?

Comment: I think it can be done. But do you need the VPN module to be created for each of the subnet IDs, for one or an arbitrary number?

Comment: @MarkoE the vpn module requires the id of a subnet called "GatewaySubnet", which is created by the network module.

Comment: Ok, can you share how the output looks like as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need only the `GatewaySubnet` then you can create an output like this:

```
output "gateway_subnet_id" {
  value = azurerm_subnet.main-subnets["GatewaySubnet"].id
}
```

Then in the second module call, you would do the following:

```
module "vpn-azure" {
  source                    = "../../modules/AZURE/vpn"
  app_name                  = var.app_name
  environment               = var.environment
  resource_group            = var.azure_resource_group_name
  region                    = var.azure_region
  gateway_subnet_id         = module.network-azure.gateway_subnet_id
}
```